# how to get index of same object when compare 2 nsmuatablearray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have 2 array :

```
array1 = "a", "b", "c","d";
array2 = "c", "b";
=> array3 = "2", "1"; // array get index from array1
```

i want to get index from array1 when objects in array2 is equals array1. **I used this code but it not correct when array2 has only 1 object.**

```
for (id obj in array2) {
   if([array1 containsObject:obj]){
       [array3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[array1 indexOfObject:obj]]];
 }
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: How is it "not correct"? This should work fine with any elements.

Comment: Replacing `templatetag` with `array1` on the third line of your code snippet should make it work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nice catch. And maybe closing the curly braces properly would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Monolo DW, it happens :)

Comment: I don't know why so. If aaray2 has only 1 object, array3 is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet should work once you fix some obvious errors. You can speed it up by performing one search of `array1` instead of two:

```
for (id obj in array2) {
    // containsObject is a linear search; combine it with indexOfObject
    // for better performance:
    NSUInteger pos = [array1 indexOfObject:obj];
    if (pos != NSNotFound) {
        [array3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:pos]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still same. If array2 has only 1 object, array3 is empty

Comment: @user2669713 This means that the only object of `array2` is missing from `array1`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes, object in array2 is missed. Do you have any suggestion ? thanks

Comment: @user2669713 If  object in array2 is missing, then returning an empty array should be the expected thing. If you must have a value for each element of `array2`, either add `[NSNull null]` in the `else` branch, or remove the `if` condition to insert `-1` for the missing objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ordered sets. Create a set of all intersecting objects, all objects that are found within both arrays. Than iterate over this intersection set and get the index in array1 of every object present in the set.

full command line example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        NSArray *array1 = @[@"a", @"b", @"c",@"d"];
        NSArray *array2 = @[@"c",@"b"];
        NSMutableArray *array3 = [@[] mutableCopy];

        NSMutableOrderedSet *intersectSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array2];
        [intersectSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:array1]];

        for (id obj in intersectSet) {
            [array3 addObject:@([array1 indexOfObject:obj])];
        }
        // array3 contains (2, 1)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that if the array1 holds identical objects, this will only return the first index.